# Why are Western helicopters more expensive, yet smaller in size, but Russian helicopters are way less expensive, and larger in size?

Tags: helicopter, cost, rotorcraft

So, I was looking around for prices of the Bell 412, Blackhawk and Mil Mi 8/17 prices, and the Bell 412, despite being a lot smaller than the Mi8, was US$2mil more than the Mi8.

Comment: source for prices? New or used?

Comment: The cost of these types of aircraft is *so much more* than just the window sticker. Take into account getting it serviced (an Mi8 might be a good alternative to the Bell 412 *if you are only operating it in Russia*), spare parts, lead time, availability of service centers, etc. That Mi8 might be cheap, but try containerizing it and sending it to Russia for service every year or two...

Comment: There might also be some currency conversion & export factors to be considered, for much the same reason that it is (or was, last I looked) cheaper to buy former Soviet bloc jet fighters than US ones.

Comment: Everybody knows it costs more to make things smaller & lighter.

Comment: @Jpe61 multiple websites. Im generalising prices here.

Comment: Because they are of better quality than Russian helicopters?

Comment: labour and material cost for construction is quite a bit lower in Russia than it is in the west. Environmental regulations and other artificial means inflating the price tend to also be less there.

Answer (score 3):

**It's just market.**

Like most markets, it's not even entirely rational. In the end, people may just have preferences. It commonly happens that a car X is cheaper than Y (and/or depreciates more), despite being better on every *objective* measure as a vehicle. But on the Y's side may be long-term reputation, familiarity, etc.

Still, there are many perfectly rational reasons for such disparity (lower cost of Russian aircraft), particularly in the West.

- Service cost and, even more importantly, its availability. Russia is not particularly renown for its after-sales service, [even within the country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Superjet_100#Dependability). A grounded aircraft is a big money drain.
- Likewise, availability and cost of pilots for such less common aircraft. This includes training, licensing them etc.
- Typically higher fuel consumption per unit payload (for the same generation of aircraft).
- Typically smaller service intervals and shorter overall lifetime. This is partly due to military origin of most Soviet/Russian helicopters.
- Depreciation and later sale prospects. This is somewhat a vicious circle, but it's an important factor affecting purchasing decision.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has answered I would assume this is almost entirely down to regulator costs. Organisations like the FAA and EASA require so many independent tests and paperwork its probably harder in a "western" country to certify an aircraft than to design one. If you can find a Russian aircraft that meets western certification it should be more comparable in price to western aircraft.
You will likely find that non-Russian helicopters that are not certified for normal flight operations (ie. X-military, experimental), are comparable in price to similar Russian aircraft.

Comment: Mi-8 and Mi-17 are operated all over the world including western countries, so they are almost certainly certified just like the Bell ones.

Comment: Many (most?) of the ones I have scene are used exclusively for stuff like helicopter logging, those are often operated under less strict maintenance and inspection rules. I do not have personal experience with the exact rules they operate under.